# How to record Cold boot with windows performance recorder?

Tags: windows, boot

I'm facing an issue with windows 11 starting twice. First the manufacturer logo appears and then it goes back starts again but this time successfully boots in to windows after the logo. This only happens on a cold boot from a normal shutdown. I'm trying to use Windows Performance Recorder to analyze what exactly causing it to boot a second a time. However while trying with all performance scenarios in the tool, the tool will restart the system. But my issue is not reproducible on a restart but only on a cold boot from a machine that is shutdown normally. How do make the windows performance recorder run and record for a cold boot?

Comment: (1) Are you doing it [this way](https://illuminati.services/2021/09/17/how-to-collect-a-boot-trace-on-windows-10-with-windows-performance-recorder-from-the-microsoft-adk/)? (2) Looking into the Event Viewer might be more useful than WPR. (3) Check the SMART data of the disks. (4) Run `chkdsk`. (5) Test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Yes, i've tried sfc, chkdsk. The page on the link you've provided tells me the performance recorder will reboot the OS which will not work for my case since my issue only happens on a normal boot from shutdown state(no hibernate). Restart is booting my OS normally. I didn't check eventviewer however since i thought it only records events that happen after login.

Comment: Event Viewer records all events, not only login-connected ones.

Comment: @harrymc Eventviewer does show a critical error happening during boot time but the message is generic. "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first." Crashed or lost power unexpectedly. However there are no memory dump files created. Is there a way to check the specific reason or drivers that is causing the issue?

Comment: @harrymc Doesn't look like it'll of much help in identifying the issue but here's the link to eventviewer XML https://ctxt.io/2/AACQ-0crEA

Answer (score 0):

The event information shows that the bug check code is zero :

```
<EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data>
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data>
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data>
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data>
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data>
```

According to the article
[Advanced troubleshooting for Event ID 41](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/event-id-41-restart) :

> Event ID 41 isn't recorded or the bug check code is zero. This behavior might indicate a power supply problem. If the power to a computer is interrupted, the computer might shut down without generating a Stop error. If it does generate a Stop error, it might not finish writing the error codes to disk. The next time the computer starts, it might not log Event ID 41. Or, if it does, the bug check code is zero. The following conditions might be the cause:
>
> - In the case of a portable computer, the battery was removed or drained.
> - In the case of a desktop computer, the computer was unplugged or experienced a power outage.
> - The power supply is underpowered or faulty.

The last option seems to be the only one that is relevant to your case.
I suggest to check the power supply.

Question : How old is the power supply ?

Comment: It's a new laptop and only a year old. there is no power supply issue since this issue occurs in a very specific usecase. Manufacturers hardware diagnostic tool couldn't find any issue with hardware. Battery health is in good condition.